# APT Pinning dependencies resolution

Tags: debian, apt, dependencies

I'm trying to master how APT pinning works under Debian, but I'm having a hard time grasping how it resolves priorities.

I have a `source.list` file that has the following entries in this exact order:

```
deb <repository> stretch main
deb <repository> testing main
deb <repository> unstable main
```

The following repository contains these packages per branch:

- stretch contains the package `dependency version 1.0`;
- testing contains the package `dependency version 2.0`;
- unstable contains the packages `program` and `dependency version 2.0`;

The package `program` depends on `dependency version 2.0`.

I need to install the package `program`, but I want to install as few packages as possible from `unstable`, so I create the following `preferences` file to pin this branch:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: -1
```

If I understand correctly how it works, it should install packages from `unstable` only when I explicitly tell APT to.

I also create a `apt.conf` file to ensure the `stable` branch is the default:

```
APT::Default-Release "stable";
```

After running the command `apt-get update`, the branches should have the following priorities:

```
stable: 990
testing: 500
unstable: -1
```

Now I want to install the package `program`, to do so, I run the following command:

```
apt-get install -t unstable program
```

So now my question is, from which branch will APT pull the package `dependency version 2.0`? As both `testing` and `unstable` have the same version of the package, which one will get picked?

If I understand correctly, APT with the `-t unstable` option, will set a 990 priority to the packages belonging to `unstable`, but from what I've experienced, it pulls it from `testing`.

So why does APT pulls packages from `testing` that has a priority of 500 while `unstable` as its set to 990? Also, what would be the optimal way to install as few packages as possible from `unstable`?

Comment: If the version is the same, then the file is **the same** also. Apt chooses the fastest or the 1st defined mirror, but the url of the downloaded file is the same. Check it yourself. Debian repositories doesn't store two identical files/version of a package due to disk space issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is explained in [the `apt_preferences` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/apt_preferences.5):

> Several versions of a package may be available for installation when the sources.list(5) file contains references to more than one distribution (for example, stable and testing). APT assigns a priority to each version that is available. Subject to dependency constraints, `apt-get` selects the version with the highest priority for installation. The APT preferences override the priorities that APT assigns to package versions by default, thus giving the user control over which one is selected for installation.
>
> Several instances of the same version of a package may be available when the sources.list(5) file contains references to more than one source. In this case `apt-get` downloads the instance listed earliest in the sources.list(5) file. The APT preferences do not affect the choice of instance, only the choice of version.

Priorities only determine which version (as specified by the version number) of a package is installed. Once that’s determined, the first available package repository is used to download it.